# TCP RST Connection - Netflix - Only on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, ip, tcp, netflix

I wouldn't have asked this here, but I am at wit's end, this makes *absolutely* no sense at this point. I have been trying everything. I have a single iptables rule:

`-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

Where `eth0` is my WAN connection going to my cable modem. All other connectivity appears fine, 110/12mbps testing to the internet using whatever speedtest site. 900mbps iperf to the router.

The only change from the netflix app running on my vizio tv working to not working was a change from a Netgear R7000 router to a linux based (debian 8) router. Everything is ethernet. If I plug the tv straight into the cable modem it works fine as well.

Setting the DNS on the TV statically, but still taking a DHCP lease off the debian box still makes it fail.

Always the error is `ui-113`

Once I Swapped hardware, reinstalled debian. It worked for a short while. Then it went back to same behavior. Absolutely no idea what it could be at this point. Has anyone ever seen this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer thanks to [this good sir](https://serverfault.com/questions/309691/why-is-our-firewall-ubuntu-8-04-rejecting-the-final-packet-fin-ack-psh-wit)

The key being

```
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
```

As seen in the linked post the sending web server was sending packets over-sequence.

I hope this helps someone else.